# How to delete my last push on gitlab with android studio

Tags: git, android-studio, gitlab

I want to delete my last push on gitlab and the adjustments still in project

note that there is someone push after me on gitlab

how to do this?

Comment: you need to rewrite the entire repository history. There is no way to "undo" a push. Also, you'll need to rewrite history for all the rest of the people as well. I'd suggest that you do yet another push, undoing the changes in the files you made with the first push.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you want to completely erase it from history (or at least try and hope nobody has a local copy), the easiest approach would be to revert it and not touch the history. `git revert` would create a commit that undoes the commit you want to undo, which you can then push like any other commit:

```
$ git revert <commit hash>
$ git push origin
```